# Como coloca um Text do tkinter em uma variavel como str?

Tags: python, tkinter

Eu criei esse código e tive a intenção de que, quando eu clicar em `print`, automaticamente ele escreva no Terminal tudo que tinha escrito no `Text`:

```
from tkinter import *

janela=Tk()

#cores
branco="white"
preto="black"
cinza="gray"

#confg da janela
janela["bg"]=branco
janela.geometry("500x500+50+50")

#funções
def opa():
    print(texto.get())

#objetos da tela
framepri=LabelFrame(janela,bg=preto)
salvar=Button(janela,bg=preto,text="print",fg=branco,command=opa)
texto=Text(janela,bg=branco,fg=preto)

#posições dos objetos
framepri.pack(anchor=NW)
texto.pack(anchor=NW)
salvar.pack(anchor=NW)

#----------------------
janela.mainloop()`
```

mas ao compilar, executar, escrever algo no `Text` e apertar em `print`, esse é o resultado:

```
    print(texto.get())
TypeError: get() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index1'
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltam-lhe parâmetros para o `get` que está a chamar.
Se olhar para os [tutoriais da própria documentação](https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/text.html) repara no seguinte:

> Retrieving the Text
> After users have made any changes and submitted the form (for example), your program can retrieve the contents of the widget via the get method:
> `thetext = text.get('1.0', 'end')`

Ou seja, o `get` que obtém o texto precisa de dois parâmetros, um para a posição de inicio e outro para a de fim, também explicados no link que referi:

> The two parameters are the start and end position; end has the obvious meaning. You can provide different start and end positions if you want to obtain only part of the text. You'll see more on positions shortly.

A ideia destes parâmetros é que nós conseguimos obter apenas parte do texto se assim o quisermos.

Para aplicar isto no seu código basta trocar a função que tem para:

```
def opa():
    texto_inserido = texto.get('1.0', 'end')
```

E agora faz o que tem que fazer com esse `texto_inserido`.